# filter dataframe based on path graph (network problem)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have this data frame:

```
df = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'w', 't', 'y', 'r', 's', 'n', 'm', 'p'],
        'col2': ['b', 'c','d','e','f', 'x', 'z', 'w', 'w', 'n', 'm', 'p', 'q'],
        'col3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}
```

or in the form of

```
   col1 col2 col3
0    a   b    1
1    b   c    2
2    c   d    3
3    d   e    4
4    e   f    5
5    w   x    6
6    t   z    7
7    y   w    8
8    r   w    9
9    s   n   10
10   n   m   11
11   m   p   12
12   p   q   13
```

I want an output where I can have at least 3 edges between the nodes `col1` and `col2`.

Here is an expected output:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0    a   b    1
1    b   c    2
2    c   d    3
3    d   e    4
4    e   f    5
9    s   n   10
10   n   m   11
11   m   p   12
12   p   q   13
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*at least 3 edges between the nodes col1 and col2*". There are not 3 edges between a and b for example

Comment: Also the provided DataFrame constructor doesn't give the shown DataFrame as text

Comment: What I meant by at least 3 edges is that, to generate the new Dataframe there must be at least 3 rows that forms a path for example: index 0-4 from col1 a to col2 f, there's 5 edges.

Comment: rows 5, 6, 7 also form a path `y -> w -> x -> z`, in a graph order should not matter, is this the case here?

Comment: my bad, I have changed row 6 col1 to t. yes, order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're trying to do is get rid of nodes in components of the graph in which the longest path includes fewer than 4 nodes (3 edges).  The following code should accomplish that, if (and only if) your limit is 3 or fewer edges.  If you're looking to expand it to components with 4 or more edges, you'll have to modify it to check all nodes with a degree of 1 in each component, rather than just one of them.  I pulled out the nodes with a degree of 1 since they'll be at the end of any longest path, so there's no sense checking all of the other nodes as well.

It's probably not the most elegant way to approach things, but it works!

To start with, create the graph with the following:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'col1', 'col2')
```

Next, we pull out all of the components in the graph.  Components are individual subsets nodes that are connected to one another but not to any other nodes. `nx_connected_components()` returns a generator that can be iterated over, but we can't modify the graph while iterating over the generator, so we pop the sets of nodes into a list instead.

The `for` loop could be shortened, but that would greatly reduce the readability so I kept the different operations on separate lines.

```
components = [component for component in nx.connected_components(G)] # List of sets of nodes

for component in components:

    # This line gets the first node from each component that matches the condition.
    # No sense looping through all of the nodes if you can just use the first one.
    end_node = next(node for node in component if G.degree(node) == 1)
    
    # The shortest_path algorithm returns a dictionary for the node keyed with the names
    # of all other nodes. The values for each key are the nodes in the path to get to that node.
    # So this checks to see if the number of nodes in the path is less than 4.
    if max([len(path) for path in nx.shortest_path(G, end_node).values()]) < 4:
        G.remove_nodes_from(component) # Removes the whole component if the path isn't long enough

# Return only rows in the dataframe that contain nodes that are still in the graph
df = df.loc[df['col1'].isin(G.nodes())]
```

As expected, here's the output:

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     a    b     1
1     b    c     2
2     c    d     3
3     d    e     4
4     e    f     5
9     s    n    10
10    n    m    11
11    m    p    12
12    p    q    13
```